# Build PDFBox FAILURE in jempbox

Tags: build, pdfbox

I found pdfbox-1.6.0.jar doesn't work on my system so, I tried to build it from Source and installed Maven.

I got this error while building either on Windows XP or Fedora 15:

```
Tests run: 8, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.077 sec <<< FAILURE!
testDateList(org.apache.jempbox.xmp.XMPSchemaTest)  Time elapsed: 0.007 sec  <<< FAILURE!
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<19800000> but was:<18060000>
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
    at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:283)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:64)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:195)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:201)
    at org.apache.jempbox.xmp.XMPSchemaTest.assertEquals(XMPSchemaTest.java:249)
    at org.apache.jempbox.xmp.XMPSchemaTest.testDateList(XMPSchemaTest.java:312)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1009)
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in PDFBox, see ([PDFBOX-1157](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1157)). Until the bug is fixed, you can work around the issue by disabling tests during your Maven build, like this:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```